# What's wrong with this trigger?

Tags: mysql, ide, triggers, syntax-error, heidisql

I'm using MySql with HeidiSql as an IDE. I have the following trigger:

```
BEGIN
declare blobpassed blob(50);
declare gid integer(10);
select lt.groupid into gid, GROUP_CONCAT(passed) into blobpassed from latest_tests lt
    left join testcaseresults tcr on tcr.testcaseresultsid = lt.tcrid
    left join grouping g on g.groupid = lt.groupid

    where lt.tcrid = NEW.testcaseresultsid
group by lt.groupid;

if blobpassed REGEXP '[1,]+' THEN 
update grouping g
set g.haspassed = 1
where g.groupid = gid;
END;
```

But it keeps saying that there is a syntax error around `GROUP_CONCAT(passed) into blobpassed from latest_tests lt`. Usually, those errors mean that there is something wrong before that (so, in this case, with gid). But i don't see what I'm doing wrong.

Can someone tell me what am I doing wrong? Thanks.

Comment: Are you using this code with the rest of the trigger parts something like this `CREATE TRIGGER trigget_name`... `delimiter`....`delimiter;`?

Answer (score 0):

In [SELECT ... INTO](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/select-into.html) the "into" part is written only once, with a variable list, so the correct query would be:

```
select lt.groupid, GROUP_CONCAT(passed) into gid, blobpassed from latest_tests lt
    left join testcaseresults tcr on tcr.testcaseresultsid = lt.tcrid
    left join grouping g on g.groupid = lt.groupid
    where lt.tcrid = NEW.testcaseresultsid
```

The "into" part can also be placed after the query:

```
select lt.groupid, GROUP_CONCAT(passed) from latest_tests lt
    left join testcaseresults tcr on tcr.testcaseresultsid = lt.tcrid
    left join grouping g on g.groupid = lt.groupid
    where lt.tcrid = NEW.testcaseresultsid
    into gid, blobpassed
```